# WP7 - Lost object's reference when making an asynchronous request/response

Tags: windows-phone-7, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am making a request to a service and getting a response. Service works fine and I am deserializing an object without a problem.

Below is an example of my code. The problem is the result object is null at the end. I do not know why am I losing a reference. What is the proper solution?

```
        HttpWebRequest hwrq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://service.svc/Login");
        hwrq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; encoding='utf-8'";
        hwrq.Accept = "text/xml";
        hwrq.Method = "POST";

        Users result = null; // object initializaiton

        hwrq.BeginGetRequestStream(ar =>
        {
            var requestStream = hwrq.EndGetRequestStream(ar);
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(requestStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                sw.Write("Username Password");
                sw.Close();
            }

            hwrq.BeginGetResponse(a =>
            {
                var response = hwrq.EndGetResponse(a);
                var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    returnedXML = sr.ReadToEnd();

                    XmlSerializer xds = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Users));

                    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(returnedXML);
                    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

                    result = (Users)xds.Deserialize(stream); // object is correct
                }
                responseStream.Close();
                response.Close();
            }, null);
        }, null);

        return result; // object is null!
```

Comment: The `return` statement is executed before `BeginGetResponse` callback is fired, so the return is null and that's nothing wrong and unusual there.

Comment: Where in code should I return my object then if not at the end of method?

Comment: You shouldn't return this object. You should use some kind of callback instead.

Comment: This is something new for me. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like MarcinJuraszek suggested, the proper way is to make a callback and handle the results there.